# Full calendar, hiding loader on timeout refresh

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar to display event data via json

It's set to refresh events every 10 seconds with the following

```
    /* Reload the calendar */
    window.setInterval(function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    }, 100000);
```

and this works fine.

I have since used the loading element on fullcalendar to show a 'loader' when the calendar is doing something using the following

```
        loading: function( isLoading, view ) {
            if(isLoading) {// isLoading gives boolean value
                $('#loader').addClass('__loading');
            } else {
                $('#loader').removeClass('__loading');
            }
        }
```

This also works fine.

However having a loader pop up every 10 seconds can be annoying.

What is the best way to keep the timeout refresh (so that uers can see up to date event data without refreshing the physical page) but prevent the loader from showing ONLY on the timeout event?

Comment: I am not sure of your requirements. You want to keep the refresh but the loading icon can be annoying? Are you loading a large amount of events? Is your loading icon taking up a lot of the calendar? Disabling use of the calendar? I use a loading icon but it is small and off to the side of the calendar header. You could always not display the icon and have the loading just happen silently, or make it smaller.

Comment: When the user performs an action on fullcalendar (such as change view, edit event, change date, etc) I want the loader to be displayed. When the calendar is refreshed automatically I want the loader to be hidden (so as not to keep popping up and annoying clients